# Magento 1.9 Strange tax rate on invoice and at the order summary in the admin area

Tags: magento

when a percentual discount (Shopping Cart Price Rules) is applied to an order the pricing looks fine in the shopping cart and also during the checkout process.

**Shopping Cart & Ceckout**

|  | amount |
| --- | --- |
| Subtotal | 13,90 € |
| Discount 10% | -1,39 € |
| Shipping Cost | 5,00 € |
| Tax | 0,00 € |
| Total | 17,51 € |

But when I have a look at the order in the admin area I see a strange tax called US-NY-*-Rate 1 (8.375%) which also appears on the invoice.

**Order in admin area & Invoice**

|  | amount |
| --- | --- |
| Subtotal | 13,90 € |
| Shipping Cost | 5,00 € |
| Discount 10% | -1,39 € |
| US-NY-*-Rate 1 (8.375%) | 1.113,88 € |
| Tax | 0,00 € |
| Total | 17,51 € |

I have no idea where the Rate "US-NY-*-Rate 1 (8.375%)" comes from. I have no Tax Rule or Tax Zone configuration like that. And as you can see the amount of that rate does not even contribute to the total amount.

Can some tell me please please how I get rid of this rate.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check in your backend > Sales > Tax:

[image]

You can see the rule in second row. If you do not want it, click on the role and click the button *Delete Rate*.